# How to use If/Then with IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

This program is using a website's API to scrape the latest sale. This program works fine for products that have recent sales, but not for one's that don't have a recent sale within the last day.

The array is [] and I of course get the IndexError: list index is out of range.

Here is my code:

```
import requests

cybersole_url = 'https://www.botbroker.io/bots/6/chart?key_type=lifetime&days=1'
response = requests.get(cybersole_url)
response.raise_for_status()
if (response.json()[0][1] == None):
    cyber = "No recent sales."
else:
    cyber = "$" + str(response.json()[0][1])
```

How can I work around this error to get one of the two results listed in my if statement? I believe I used try and except, but it only performed the except even when it had objects in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests

cybersole_url = 'https://www.botbroker.io/bots/6/chart?key_type=lifetime&days=1'
response = requests.get(cybersole_url)
response.raise_for_status()

# Try to index the result, otherwise set result=None
try:
    result = response.json()[0][1]
except IndexError:
    result = None

cyber = 'No recent sales.' if not result else f'${result}'
```

Note you might want to add another layer of try-catching since you not only want to grab the element at `[0]`, but also the element at `[0][1]` – there are two layers of indexing here.